# log4j2 configuration from file

Tags: spring, log4j, log4j2

I am working on an existing system that uses log4j, I want to update to log4j2.

There is a custom spring bean that loads the configuration from a file. I need to keep this approach. I cannot use the "log4j.configurationFile" system property.

We have a properties file where the path to the current log4j.xml is specified ( NFS share )

The spring bean has this code ...

```
public class Log4jConfigurationBean implements ResourceLoaderAware,
    InitializingBean {

private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

private boolean enabled;

private String location;

/**
 * Default, no argument constructor.
 */
public Log4jConfigurationBean() {
    enabled = true;
}

/**
 * Sets whether or not this bean should load an external configuration
 * defined by {@link #setLocation(Resource)}. If <code>false</code>, this
 * bean does nothing.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Default value is <code>true</code>.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param enabled
 *            <code>false</code> causes this bean to do nothing
 */
public void setEnabled(final boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

/**
 * Sets the location of the external log4j configuration (xml or properties)
 * to be loaded.
 * 
 * @param location
 *            the location of the external configuration to be loaded.
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *             if there is a problem resolving the location resource
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if <code>resource</code> is <code>null</code>
 */
public void setLocation(final String location) {
    this.location = StringUtils.trimToNull(location);
}

@Override
public void setResourceLoader(final ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}

/**
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *             if enabled and no location has be set, or if the external
 *             configuration is neither xml or properties.
 */
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    URL configURL = null;
    if (null != location) {
        try {
            final Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(location);
            if (null != resource) {
                configURL = resource.getURL();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Could not resolve configuration location due to error: ",
                    e);
        }
    }
    if (enabled && null == configURL) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Log4j configuration enabled, but configuration location is not set.");
    }
    if (enabled) {
        if (configURL.getFile().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
            DOMConfigurator.configure(configURL);
        } else if (configURL.getFile().toLowerCase()
                .endsWith(".properties")) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(configURL);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Configuration must be properties or xml: "
                            + configURL.getFile());
        }
    }
}
```

}

In log4j2 there is no PropertyConfigurator. 
How can I load the log4j2.xml file the same way.

The file path to the log4j2.xml file is specified in a spring property file.

The goal is to have the war files contain a log4j2.xml file in the classpath. This will be used when developing on your local box.

When the web apps are deployed to a qa environment, there is a property file containing the following key/value pair...

```
# Should an external file be used for log4j configuration
log4j.enabled=true
log4j.location=file:/paht to log4j2.xml
```

A spring bean is using these values to decide if an external log4j2.xml file should be used instead of the one on the classpath.

I tried with a spring bean like this... the code is executed, but it still uses the configuration file on the classpath.

```
public class Log4j2ConfigurationBean implements ResourceLoaderAware, InitializingBean {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4j2ConfigurationBean.class);
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
private boolean enabled;
private String location;

/**
 * Default, no argument constructor.
 */
public Log4j2ConfigurationBean() {
    enabled = true;
}

/**
 * Sets whether or not this bean should load an external configuration defined by {@link #setLocation(Resource)}. If <code>false</code>, this bean does nothing.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Default value is <code>true</code>.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param enabled
 *            <code>false</code> causes this bean to do nothing
 */
public void setEnabled(final boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

/**
 * Sets the location of the external log4j configuration (xml or properties) to be loaded.
 * 
 * @param location
 *            the location of the external configuration to be loaded.
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *             if there is a problem resolving the location resource
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if <code>resource</code> is <code>null</code>
 */
public void setLocation(final String location) {
    this.location = StringUtils.trimToNull(location);
}

@Override
public void setResourceLoader(final ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}

/**
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *             if enabled and no location has be set, or if the external configuration is neither xml or properties.
 */
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    URL configURL = null;
    if (enabled) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(location)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Log4j2 configuration enabled, but configuration location is not set.");
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " : Loading log4j2 configuration with " + location);
            final Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(location);
            if (null != resource) {
                configURL = resource.getURL();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not resolve configuration location due to error: ", e);
        }
        if (configURL.getFile().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
            try {
                System.setProperty("Log4jContextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");
                System.setProperty("AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize", "8192");
                ConfigurationFactory configurationFactory = XmlConfigurationFactory.getInstance();
                ConfigurationSource configurationSource = new ConfigurationSource(configURL.openStream(), configURL);
                Configuration configuration = configurationFactory.getConfiguration(configurationSource);
                configuration.start();
                log.info("Log4j2 configured with {}", location);
                log.info("System property Log4jContextSelector set to {}", System.getProperty("Log4jContextSelector"));
                log.info("System property AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize set to {}", System.getProperty("AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " : Could not initialize log4j2 with resource " + location);
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Configuration must be xml: " + configURL.getFile());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " : External log4j2 configuration not configured.");
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **How do I configure log4j2 in code without a configuration file?** section here - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html